# How to show chart of Annual Growth Rate using highcharts in django?

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I'm trying to render **annual growth rate** using highcharts in Django. There is only one **Branch** model and in views, I'm trying to generate the queryset to group by year. As I have only one model, I'm getting specific Branch instance to that year only while I need to get all the branch instances for each year to visualize the data.

models.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


def current_year():
    return datetime.date.today().year


def max_value_current_year(value):
    return MaxValueValidator(current_year())(value)

class Branch(models.Model):

    branch_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sales_amount = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=current_year(), validators=[MinValueValidator(1984), max_value_current_year])
```

views.py

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q, Sum
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

from .models import Branch



def index(request):
    dataset = Branch.objects.values('date', 'sales_amount').annotate( sales=Count('sales_amount'))

    categories = list()
    sales = list()

    for entry in dataset:

        categories.append('Year %s' % entry['date'])
        sales.append(entry['sales_amount'])


    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'categories': json.dumps(categories),
        'sales': json.dumps(sales),
    })
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>HomePage</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css">
    <script src = "{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" ></div>
    <script src = "{% static 'highcharts/code/highcharts.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Annual Sales Growth'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: {{ categories|safe }}
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Total Sales',
                data: {{ sales }},
                color: 'green'
            },
            ]
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected result is, if I have two branches in 2015, I should have 2 histogram branch bar. And if I  add a new branch instance in 2016, there should be three histogram bar showing (previous two and recently added) or two if I've deleted one of the instances. But the actual output i'm having is there is individual bar for individual year. eg: if there are two branch instances in 2015 and one branch instances in 2016, it shows three individual branches, two bar for 2015 and one for 2016.

Comment: Hi @Sawyer, Could you provide me with an example of generated data and categories?

Comment: @ppotaczek I'm having three individual histogram bar where categories are year and data are the sales. But the expected result is to group by year (categories) where each year will have its respective branch histogram bar with the sales (data).

Comment: I understand that your chart looks similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ctnzqda0/ and you would like to achieve something like: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d6tjanu3/ ?